How to Run Specific Python Scripts in a Docker Container without Default Command?
I am trying to create a simple Python application inside Docker. I have set up a Dockerfile as follows:
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /scripts

COPY . .

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]

My docker-compose file looks like this:
services:
  scripts:
    container_name: test_con
    env_file:
      - .env
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db

  postgres_db:
    image: postgres:16.4
    container_name: test_db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - "5032:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:

The folder structure is as follows:

I do not want to run a Python script by default; instead, I want to create the Python environment and run the script I want manually. After executing docker-compose up, I entered the shell of the test_con container and attempted to run the command: python hp_sales_data_postgres.py. But it throws an error: python: can't open file '/scripts/hp_sales_data_to_postgres.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
How can I run specific Python scripts in the container without a default command? Thank you!

Why are you assuming it's running a default python script? You're actually running python in the script you're trying to run. This sounds like it cannot find the file, you should run pwd to see where you are when you're executing

@Kraigolas because of the CMD command in Dockerfile (I'm very new to docker). I ran pwd and I'm in the correct directory.

do a bit of googling and follow some tutorials

This is invalid location:
/scripts/hp_sales_data_to_postgres.py
the correct location will be
/scripts/scripts/hp_sales_data_to_postgres.py

the config you shared in question the correct will be /scripts/scripts/hp_sales_data_to_postgres.py
... changing order of cmds will change the path ... that will be a seperate question
